# how to propagate context to Router component. Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to make logged user's data global in my reactjs app.
My App code:

```
class App extends Component {
  getChildContext = () => {
    return {
      user: {
       name: 'username',
       email: 'email@rmail.com'
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/game' component={Game} />
        <Route exact path='/singup' component={Singup} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
 }

App.childContextTypes = {
 user: PropTypes.object
};
```

In Game component I try to get use through *this.context.user* but I get *undefined*.

**Can I propagate context to Router component?**

Comment: you don't need to propagate context, context is available globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By adding childContextTypes and getChildContext to the context provider, React passes the information down automatically and any component in the subtree can access it by defining contextTypes.
>   If contextTypes is not defined, then context will be an empty object.

Make sure you've defined `contextTypes` on your `Game` component

```
Game.contextTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object
};
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil Fadnis. It nice explanation. It fixed the problem.